# Underscore in Finale lyrics

Tags: finale

I need to have two syllables of different words under the same note. Precisely, the words are in Spanish, and they are "y" and "en". So I'd like to obtain "y_en" under the same note, with the underscore, not a slur, since the first word is a consonant, not a vocal. I have found out how to place a slur (switch the font to "Engraver Font Set" and type a capital I), but the underscore does not work (the std underscore causes the second word to disappear). Anyone who knows a way to accomplish my need? I am using Finale 2014.5.

Comment: Instead you should engrave the same note twice in a row with the note value for each showing the length of time you want each word to be sung and the total of the two note values adding up to the value of the current single note.

Answer (score 1):

I am using CTRL+SPACEBAR between the words which should be under the same note.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would use the underscore since, to me, the elison makes more sense. But, in order for you to get what you want you have to do as follow: If you are not using the font Times New Roman, you have to change to that font (it could be only for the character, it doesn't need to be all lyrics). While inserting the lyric or using the dialog with all lyrics already written, you go to menu Text -> Insert Symbol. Then you look for character 717 and double click it. Done.